# Consider the following subset of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: general-topology, complex-numbers

$\{\mathcal{z}\in\mathbb C| \mathcal{Re(z)} \lt  2\text{ and }\mathcal{Im(z)}\ge  3\}$

Determine whether the set is open, closed, neither or connected and justify your answer.

I am struggling on how to approach this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I rewrote the problem:

$$\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x<2 \, \,, y \geq 3\}$$
would that be helpful?

Recall that the product topology is equivalent to the usual topology in $\mathbb R^n$, so you can ask if $(U \times V)$ is open when $U:=\{x \in \mathbb R \mid x<2\}$ and $V:=\{y \in \mathbb R^2 \mid y \geq 3\}$.

You should also notice that this space must be connected (since it is convex as was stated in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Interpret this set as a subset of a plane. A topology in $\Bbb C$ is the ordinary Euclidean topology. This set is not open: find the argument. For closedness please find the answer by yourself. This set is convex, so it is connected.